# Switch between edit controls using Tab?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

The Window is non DialogBox based so WS_TABSTOP doesn't work. Moreover I don't want to Tab through all the controls, I just want to Tab through few Edit controls.

What I did is I superclassed the Edit control and handled the WM_KEYDOWN message, switching between edit controls, by getting next window in the line thorugh ::GetWindow(hwnd,GW_HWNDNEXT); Also I would like to switch focus back to the first Edit control when I have reached the last one.

The Code doesn't work for when I have reached the last Edit control, the ::GetWindow simply returns the next window in the line(?), which happens to be a non superclassed edit control. And there are more hidden child windows(SW_HIDE).

Maybe if I know how to know the class name of the window's HWND ?

Note: Pure Win32 api, c++ oop.

```
else if (  ( int ) wParam == VK_TAB  )
{
   HWND nextInLine;
   nextInLine = ::GetWindow ( hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT );
   if ( hwnd == NULL )  nextInLine = ::GetWindow ( hwnd, GW_HWNDPREV );
   ::SendMessage ( nextInLine, EM_SETSEL, ( WPARAM ) 0, ( LPARAM ) -1 );
   ::SetFocus ( nextInLine );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/21/55384.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You get keyboard navigation for free in any window by using the [`IsDialogMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx) API call. To consume the service a window message loop has to be modified to include a call to `IsDialogMessage` and only pass the message on to regular message handling if it hasn't been handled by the dialog manager already.

```
MSG msg = { 0 };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if (IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg)) {
        /* Already handled by dialog manager */
    } else {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` [extended window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) on the parent window, so that the dialog manager recurses into child windows.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get away with just [calling `IsDialogMessage`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/21/55384.aspx), but the result isn't quite 100% dialog-like. To make an ordinary window behave like a dialog:

- Specify [`DLGWINDOWEXTRA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the `cbWndExtra` field of your [`WNDCLASS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (don't forget to add on extra space you might already be using and offset your data's indexes)
- Call [`DefDlgProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than [`DefWindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Since this makes your window a dialog, you need to use the [`DWLP_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#DWLP_USER) window long instead of [`GWLP_USERDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#GWLP_USERDATA), if you're using that, when calling [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

(From memory, the main thing you get from doing the above is support for [`WM_NEXTDLGCTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which I've found useful to use for supporting changing focus using the Enter key, using Method I described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102589.)

Then in your message pump, call [`IsDialogMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for each dialog-like window in your message pump.

Finally, when creating controls for your dialog-like window, set the [`WS_TABSTOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WS_TABSTOP) window style for each window you want to participate in the tabbing, and set the [`WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT) window exstyle (aka `Control Parent` in the resource editor) for child windows that contain dialog controls.